# Unnesting? a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, nsarray

I have an NSMutableArray set up in a model class as:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) list_name
{
  NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [array addObject:@"Jack"];
  [array addObject:@"Steven"];

  return array;
}
```

which I access in a controller class as:

```
[_transferArray addObjectsFromArray:[_addModel list_name]];
```

Where `_transferArray` is a `NSMutableArray`
And `_addModel` is a `Model`

However this outputs as:

> 2014-06-15 15:03:44.775 Keeping Track[13222:607] Array PRINT - (
>           (
>           Jack,
>           Steven
>       )
>   )

Therefore I only get a count of 1 returned.

How do I use this array in an other class where the result will be:

> 2014-06-15 15:03:44.775 Keeping Track[13222:607] Array PRINT - (
>           Jack,
>           Steven
>   )

??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flatten the array. This will scale to any nesting level:

```
@interface NSArray (JRAdditions)

- (NSArray *)flattenedArray;

@end 

@implementation NSArray (JRAdditions)

- (NSArray *)flattenedArray; 
{
   NSMutableArray *flattened = [NSMutableArray new];            
   for(id obj in self) {
      if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
          [flattened addObjectsFromArray:[obj flattenedArray]];
      } else {
          [flattened addObject:obj];
      }
   }
   return [flattened copy]; 
}

@end

@interface NSMutableArray (JRAdditions)
- (void)flatten;
@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (JRAdditions)

- (void)flatten;
{
   [self setArray:[self flattenedArray]];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks - I will give this a go. I forgot to say that my array is nested inside an other array, but it has to stay there. So will report back.